# Hibernate Issue in Native Sql while fetching columns from multiple tables?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql

Assume there are two tables. Table A and Table B.

Table A has {id, name, desc}
Table B has {id, name, place}

I'm trying to display the name, id columns where a.id equals b.id.

Hibernate is not displaying records properly.

Could someone help me with the solution?

Thanks,
Kathir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write this type of queries like this:

```
 Query qry = session.createQuery("select a.name, a.id from A a, B b where a.id = b.id");
 List l = qry.list();
 Iterator it = l.iterator();
 while(it.hasNext())
 {
     Object o[] = (Object o[])it.next();
     System.out.println("name = "+o[0]+" id = "+o[0]);

 }
```

In this case hibernate internally stores the multiple column values of each row into an object array and stores these object arrays into List collection. At the time of iterating the collection, we need to typecast the result into an object arrays.

Cheers and Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to alias your tables.

```
select a.name, a.id from A a join B b on a.id = b.id
```